# React/Redux - Update state in parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I've 2 components: Header and Child in an already developed `react` application that uses `redux-saga`.

Header component has 2 material-ui Select component. Now when I route to child component I want to disable those 2 Select component in Header by updating it's state.

`App.js`

```
const App = ({ store }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Header />
        <Router />
        <Footer />
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

`Router.js`

```
<Route
        exact
        path={`${url}BatchFileRawDataDashboard`}
        component={Child}
      />
```

`Header.js`

```
<Select
  style={{ width: 112 }}
  value={this.state.selectedCycle}
  autoWidth={true}
  disabled={this.disableCycle.bind(this)}
 >
 {cycleDateItem}
 </Select>
```

Header component has no props and I am very much confused with how `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` works.

**How to update state of parent component from child component that uses `redux`?**

Comment: There is too much to explain if you don't understand `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. Understanding `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` is a prerequisite to using redux effectively. Not only that, but `redux-saga` is an entirely different beast on its own. It is powerful, but it increases the complexity of redux by an incredible amount. That is simply too much to juggle all at once. I highly recommend you learn vanilla `redux` first

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your suggestion. Modifying something in already built large application is always difficult. Small example with respect to my question would be really helpful to understand as it will give better idea how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mapStateToProps = putting redux store state into the props

mapDispatchToProps = putting redux actions into the props

So on the child, you want to call an action that will update the store via mapDispatchToProps

Then on the parent you want to use mapStateToProps to read this updated value

```js
// PARENT READ DATA

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  parentData: store.parentData,
})


// CHILD ACTION TO UPDATE STORE

// the function here triggers a action which triggers a reducer
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateParentAction: data => dispatch(some_action_name(data)),
})
```

I suggest reading up on how redux works, it's simple once you get it, but complicated to start with https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/

Comment: I got working to disable a select in header when route to child. Now, header is common and when I route back to Home page the select in header remains disabled. How to get it enable again when not on child?

Comment: `componentWillUnmount` on child helped to reset the prop that resets the state of select in header. Thanks @Luke Robertson